# parse error in creating an array to initialize database's row

Tags: codeigniter, php

```
public function register()
{
    if(!file_exists('application/views/forum/register_view.php'))
    {            
        show_404();
    }
    $member_data=array(
                    'name'=>"<?='$_POST['register_name']'?>",
                    'email'=>"<?='$_POST['register_email']'?>",
                    'pass'=>"<?='$_POST['password']'>",
                    'activation'=>"<?=md5(uniqid(rand(),true))?>");

    $this->load->view('forums/register_view');
}
```

this is my register function which is called after the user clicks the Signup button 
activation key is used to activate his account before log in. I leave this function in controller folder. Here is what I have in the model folder

```
<?php
class Forums_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function insert_member($member_data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('regmember_tb',$member_data);    
    }
}
?>
```

The error i have got is

> syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING
>   or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

at the member_data's initialization in the register function.

My current route configuration is

```
$route['default_controller'] = "forums/login";
$route['blog/(:any)']='forums/login/$1';
```

I would like to know what else i can add to load forum_model class as I am doing in the constructor function of the controller class

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('forums_model');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('email');  
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: if register() is a function in your controller, why are you using PHP short tags in your member_data array?

Answer (score 4):

you don't need all this `"<?='...` stuff.

just

```
$member_data=array(
                'name'=>$_POST['register_name'],
                'email'=>$_POST['register_email'],
                'pass'=>$_POST['password'],
                'activation'=>md5(uniqid(rand(),true)));
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, but I need to correct my route config file to load this model. Please read my editted post for more details.

Comment: @user1125524, this explains the syntax error. However, after fixing this your code still won't work because `$member_data` doesn't magically pass to the model. You have to instantiate the model and call `insert_member` on the instance with `$member_data` as an argument.

Comment: Don't use $_POST see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

change this

```
$member_data=array(
                'name'=>"<?='$_POST['register_name']'?>",
                'email'=>"<?='$_POST['register_email']'?>",
                'pass'=>"<?='$_POST['password']'>",
                'activation'=>"<?=md5(uniqid(rand(),true))?>");
```

to

```
 $member_data=array(
                'name'=>$_POST['register_name'],
                'email'=>$_POST['register_email'],
                'pass'=>$_POST['password'],
                'activation'=>md5(uniqid(rand(),true)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers address your syntax errors. This addresses the fact that you seem to think that `$member_data` can be passed to the model magically. It cannot. You have to load the model and call `insert_member` with `$member_data` as an argument.

Add the following code to you controller:

```
$this->load->model('Forums_model', 'forum');
$this->forum->insert_member($member_data);
```

Comment: Yes, it works not but the member insertion fails. I make another thread now.

Answer (score 0):

Why show the models if you didn't use it in your controller?

I highly discourage using the raw `$_POST` array. CodeIgniter wraps `$_POST` into a function called `$this->input->post();` It performs sql injection, and xss prevention algorithms. It generally cleans your input and ensures what you're working with is safe.

You can turn on global xss filtering in your `config/config.php` file

```
if(!file_exists('application/views/forum/register_view.php'))
{            
   show_404();
}
$p = $this->input->post();
$member_data=array
(
    'name'=> $p['register_name'],
    'email'=> $p['register_email'],
    'pass'=> $p['password'],
    'activation' => md5(uniqid(rand(),true))
);

//are you going to do anything with $member_data?

$this->load->view('forums/register_view');
```

Comment: Thank you, I would like to call insert_member function in the forum_model class

Comment: @user1125524, my answer explains how to do that.